# Wrong TYPO3 Page Cache

Tags: php, caching, typo3, realurl

This Problem occurs sporadically on Pages with a large Number of visitors.
Sometimes TYPO3 displays the content of a completely different page (including the HTML head Section).

For example, if the user calls the following page: `/products/` (default Controller `ProductController` with `listAction`) TYPO3 shows the content of a random Controller and action of the same Plugin on the Page (like `ApplicationController` with `showAction`).
The Site does not redirect to another Page, it's just showing wrong content!

I already tried the following things:

- I added the Controller + action to the `nonCacheableControllerActions` (Problem occurs a day later again)
- Adding `?no_cache=1` to the URL (Problem is solved, but the page speed is reduced)
- Clearing Cache (Problem is solved, no matter what cache is cleared. But the Problem occurs a day later again)
- I wrote a script which called the page every few minutes which seems to fix the problem.

Does anybody else have the same Problem?

Specifications:

- TYPO3 Version: `7.6.22`
- realurl Version: `2.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those caching problems are usually occuring because of wrong or missing cHashes.

You can use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']→reqCHash();`
in your controller's actions. This disables Caching if no cHash is set, therefore making sure you don't get incorrect cache entries.
Please note: If you set [pageNotFoundOnCHashError] = 1 in your system settings you will get page not found errors when the page is called without cHash, if it's set to 0 the page will still be displayed but not cached.

---

*The following information may be outdated, see moe2k's answer below for more current information.*

Alternatively, there is a system parameter "[FE][cHashRequiredParameters]" - you can add your plugin parameters there. If no cHash is given but one of the parameters are set, then TYPO3 triggers the configured cHash Error behaviour.
I believe cHashes are then set automatically for typolinks, you can try and see though. If they aren't set automatically you should set "useCacheHash = 1" on your links to the show action.

I prefer & use the first variant.

Comment: My `[pageNotFoundOnCHashError]` value is already set to `1`. But TYPO3 does not trigger the Error. I will try the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']→reqCHash();` call tomorrow. But i wonder how the cache problem could happen. How could i prevent the problem in the future?

Comment: Yes, but even though your pageNotFoundOnCHashError is set, no error might be trigger because your extension doesn't explicitly require cHashes. 
The Cache problem usually occurs when an action is called without cHash after the Cache has been cleared - then the non-hashed page gets into your Cache and will be delivered for all future calls - with out without cHash. We've had that many times. 
We now set $GLOBALS['TSFE']→reqCHash(); in all actions where we want individual Cache Entries. Haven't had Problems since.

Comment: TYPO3 6.x+ sets cHash by default, and you have to set NoCacheHash to avoid generating cHash values.

Which is why I suggest using USER_INT to verify that its not an error in record updates, invalidating cHash values.

Its not pretty, its not the preferred way, but it'll help you find the real issue. And have your page working while you do it.

Comment: @Nano did you ever figure it out? I have a very similar issue

Comment: @Noch_ein_Kamel The Problem was solved, after using `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->reqCHash()`

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the plugin as USER_INT.
plugin.tx_yourextkey = USER_INT

This will tell TYPO3 to render the code for each request.

Best practice would be a second page for the showAction, and only on the single_view page, define the plugin as USER_INT.

But is you have two pages for this you should not experience this problem. And not need the USER_INT setting.

Comment: I personally don't think that's a good idea – USER_INT makes the plugin no-cache also. Just to make that clear. "If you create this object as USER_INT, it will be rendered non-cached, outside the main page-rendering."  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

Comment: exactly, and you want it to be rendered outside main page rendering to avoid caching conflicts between list and show actions.

Comment: In some cases that would mean most of your website can't be cached, slowing everything down. That doesn't necessarily make sense. Typo3 uses cHashes to make caching possible for different actions. In some cases it makes sense to just turn of the cache, but for some cases using correct cHashes is a better solution. I might just be misunderstanding the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 v9, use the following:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['cacheHash']['requireCacheHashPresenceParameters']
```

with an array as value instead of

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['cacheHash']['cHashRequiredParameters']
```

with a comma-separated list.